# Cocoa / Interface Builder how to set up the preview in Adobe Photoshop SDK for Retina display?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder, photoshop

We have a problem with our PS plug-ins for Mac OS X when used on Apple's Retina Display MacBook Pro models. The issue is that the preview image appears multifold.The problem as such also exists with the unchanged Dissolve example from the [current PS CC SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/sdk.html).

So I’ll use that to illustrate the issue.

The Dissolve example plug-in displays a 4-up preview window on a Retina display as shown below:
[image]

Interestingly, with the dialog still up, if one connects an external display (we used Apple 27” Cinema LED display) and moves the dialog back and forth between Retina display and external display, the preview actually switches between the 4 up and the regular preview as shown below as the dialog crosses over from one display to the other.

[image]

Spontaneously we know of nothing we could do within the plug-in that would correct this but I guess the answer might be in interface builder. What we'd need to do is designate the preview to use physical pixels somehow. It reports its size back and will get used accordingly in our product.

Has anyone else solved this problem? Is it required to migrate to `Xcode Version 4.6, Base SDK 10.7, Apple LLVM compiler 4.2, OS X Deployment Target 10.6` as Adobe did with the CC SDK or can the problem also be solved using `Xcode Version 3.2.5, GCC 4.2, SDK 10.6` as used in the PS CS6 SDK?

**Edit November, 28, 2013:** Added a bounty of +50 rep. I am looking for a working step by step instruction on how to make the aforementioned Adobe PS CC SDK "Dissolve" filter example work on both Retina and regular displays.

**Edit December, 6, 2013:** Bounty expired...

Comment: The problem is that the example assumes that pixels in the image are the same as pixels in the view, and they're not. You need to take into account that on a Retina display, there are 2 pixels per point. I haven't had a chance to go through the entire example and figure out all the places this needs to be changed, but it shouldn't be too hard to do.

Comment: @user1118321 I realize that this might be a little more involved to answer thoroughly, so I added a bounty of +50 on it today.